# How to use was clause with Jql

Tags: jira

i am developing report plugin for jira where i need to get assignee for given duration.it could be diffrent than current assignee in given duration.

now i am building my query in report like below.

JqlQueryBuilder queryBuilder = JqlQueryBuilder.newBuilder();

query = queryBuilder.where().updatedBetween(stdate,endDate).and().assignee() in(status_val).buildQuery();

```
     return searchProvider.searchCount(query, remoteUser);
```

i want to get the count for prior assigned issues for given duration.

please let me know how i can use Was clause with assignee and updatedbetween dates.

regards,
tousif shaikh.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading [this answer](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/83591/how-can-i-use-advanced-search-text-in-jqlquerybuilder-java-api). In short, you'll need to define a new clause and use it in your query, like this:

```
JqlQueryBuilder builder = JqlQueryBuilder.newBuilder();
WasClauseImpl wasClause = new WasClauseImpl("status", Operator.WAS, new SingleValueOperand("Resolved"), new TerminalHistoryPredicate(Operator.AFTER, new SingleValueOperand(3500000L)));
JqlClauseBuilder clauseBuilder = JqlQueryBuilder.newClauseBuilder(wasClause);
Query query = clauseBuilder.buildQuery();
```